# Rails params for nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, nested-forms

I've been battling for days now to get data to save for my nested form. I basically want to be able to store a users reason for cancelling a project, along with the last stage of the project before it was cancelled. But I just can't seem to get the actions `cancel`, `cancel_save`, and `cancel_params` to play nicely!

**Controller**

```
before_action :correct_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :cancel, :cancel_save]

...

def cancel
  @project.build_project_close_reason
end

def cancel_save
  @project.build_project_close_reason(cancel_params)
  @project.update(project_status_id: 10)
  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Project has been successfully cancelled.'
end

private 

def correct_user
  @user = current_user
  @project = current_user.projects.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end
  redirect_to user_projects_path, notice: "You are not authorised to view this project" if @project.nil?
end

def cancel_params
  params.require(:project).permit(project_close_reason_attributes: [:comment]).merge(project_close_reason_attributes: [project_id: @project.id, last_status_id: @project.project_status_id ])
end
```

**Models**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :project_close_reason
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_close_reason #adding this seemed to make no difference?
end

class ProjectCloseReason < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
... # All standard devise stuff
  has_many :projects
end
```

**Nested form in the view**

```
<%= form_for([@user, @project], url: {action: "cancel_save"}, method: :post) do |f| %>

<%= fields_for :project_close_reason do |pcr| %>

  <div class="field entry_box">
    <%= pcr.label "Why are you cancelling this project? (This helps us improve!)" %>
    <%= pcr.text_area :comment, class: "form-control entry_field_text" %>
  </div>


<% end %>

  <div class="actions center space_big">
    <%= f.submit "Cancel Project", class: "btn btn-lg btn-warning" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**Routes**

```
devise_for :users
devise_for :admins

resources :users do
  resources :projects do
    get "cancel", :on => :member
    post "cancel" => 'projects#cancel_save', :on => :member
  end
end
```

This is the error I get when I try and submit the form:

`ActionController::ParameterMissing in ProjectsController#cancel_save
param is missing or the value is empty: project`. It references the `cancel_params` action

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE

Here is the log when I call `cancel_save`

```
Started POST "/users/2/projects/10/cancel" for ::1 at 2016-09-29 10:03:44 +0200
Processing by ProjectsController#cancel_save as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"h6K+VFyjW/dV189YOePWZm+Pmjey50xAMQIJb+c3dzpEaMv8Ckh3jQGOWfVdlfVH/FxolbB45fXvTO0cdplhkg==", "project_close_reason"=>{"comment"=>"b"}, "commit"=>"Cancel Project", "user_id"=>"2", "id"=>"10"}
User Load (11.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Project Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."user_id" = $1 AND "projects"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 2], ["id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
ProjectCloseReason Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "project_close_reasons".* FROM "project_close_reasons" WHERE "project_close_reasons"."project_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["project_id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 12.1ms)


ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: project):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got it to work without requiring projects at all. This is my revised `cancel_params` in my `projects_controller`. For anyone else looking at doing this kind of additive databasing, I highly recommend skipping params for nested form if you can do it this way. **So much simpler!**

```
private

def cancel_params
  params.require(:project_close_reason).permit(:comment).merge(project_id: @project.id, last_status_id: @project.project_status_id )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that there is no params with name `project`, which you are trying to require in `params.require(:project)` line in `cancel params`. I think this is happening beacause in `form_for` you have mentioned `[@user, @project]`, that means `user's project`. So the `project params must be inside user's`. Check your log when you call `cancel_save`. There must be something like `{user => {project => { } }`.

Comment: I have updated the above to include the log when I run `cancel_save` action. Its strange as I have the standard `project_params` action that looks fairly similar (including the `.require(:project)` that works with the other RESTful actions?

Comment: And these are the params when I run a `new` action for projects, which works using the `project_params`. Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Wg7ZMcOfhFxXyaHcN67phcuG27eKWGt+QpF+p3wnXGSZxKyZlXSoJgOQN3FT2MqkWFUpFYjHwsuc35rU7YlKzA==", "project"=>{"project_type_id"=>"1", "name"=>"Project 6 - This is just a test name", "description"=>"This is a test description", "industry_id"=>"1", "feature_ids"=>[""], "addon_ids"=>[""], "budget_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save Project", "user_id"=>"2"}

Comment: Thank you, I got so frustrated with the nesting side, I just worked around it. Posted a new answer where I got rid of :project all together. Thanks!